# Using SQL "In" instead of "Like" using %wildcards% in Linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

If I search within a description field using Linq I receive different results when searching with these two queries. First by this `%MODULE%ALLEN BRADLEY%` and then second by this query `%ALLEN BRADLEY%MODULE%`.  I would like these search queries to give me a result where these words appear in any place of the description field.

I read about sql that using `LIKE` searches for pattern in string in a correct order, for instance searching for `%MODULE%ALLEN BRADLEY%` would force the result to be in that particular order within the string.  However using the keyword "In" searches for the wildcards anywhere within the string.

**How would I achieve that in Linq?**

*This is my Linq method:*

```
    public List<Item> SearchItems(string itemid, string description)
    {
        return (from allitems in _dbc.Items 
                where SqlMethods.Like(allitems.Number, itemid)
                && SqlMethods.Like(allitems.DESCRIPTION, description)
                select allitems);
    }
```

Comment: You shoud be using full text search for these types of search. Having a wildcard as the first character precludes the use o f indesxes ans ia sure sign that your design is bad.

Comment: Thank you for that comment @HLGEM, the design may be bad but it´s a requirement from the customer that the search should also include "starting with wildcard".  The searches with wildcard are actually user input within the system.

Comment: That's why you need to research full text search. really, it is tricky to implement, but it will solve your problem and be much faster.

Comment: You may be on to something @HLGEM, I´ve been researching full-text-search and that may be the key for my search problems.  However the solution MarcinJuraszek provided me did the trick so I´m going to stick that for now.  I will definately look better at full-text-search when I will optimize my queries.  Thank you both  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your query in more then one line and then execute it using `ToList()` method:

```
public List<Item> SearchItems(string itemid, string description)
{
    IQueryable<Item> query = _dbc.Items.Where(x => SqlMethods.Like(x.Number, itemid));

    foreach(var word in description.Split(new char[] { '%' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    {
        query = query.Where(x => SqlMethods.Like(x.Description,
                                                 string.format("%{0}%", word)));
    }

    return query.ToList();
}
```

However, as already suggested - you should consider using full text search instead.